# Equal sign key on the Apple keyboard's number pad doesn't work in Windows 8

Tags: keyboard, windows

I have an Apple, USB keyboard with the integrated number pad on the right.  I have it connected to a HP laptop running Windows 8.

When I use the number pad, I've noticed that the equal sign <kbd>=</kbd> isn't captured.  The other number pad keys [0-9.+-*/] work as expected.

Is there a way to get it to function without having to use AutoHotKey?

** edit **

Keyboard and number pad work correctly with a Mac.

Comment: Does it work correctly on a mac?

Answer (score 1):

Windows keyboards don't have an equals  <kbd>=</kbd>   on the NumPad [10-key].
The top row is NumLock, divide  <kbd>/</kbd>  , multiply  <kbd>*</kbd>  , minus  <kbd>-</kbd>

[image]

You might need AutoHotKey or similar to persuade it to work in Windows [not something I'm particularly experienced with].

Comment: Ha! That explains it! I haven't looked at a normal (aka Windows) number pad for a long time!

Answer (score 0):

You can spend hours trying to jimmy-rig it with "AutoHotKey" or you could just spend $10 and get a windows keyboard. Your choice.

Comment: To "X isn't working, how do I fix it?", "Just get rid of X" isn't really a good response.